# Audio File is not Uploading to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, audio, firebase-storage

Here is the code:

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button btn_taptorecord;
    Boolean isRecording = false;
    private String recordPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
    private String recordFile;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    StorageReference audioReference;

    private int PERMISSION_CODE = 7;


    public AddFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        btn_taptorecord = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_taptorecord);
        audioReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

        btn_taptorecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isRecording) {
                    //stop recording
                    stopRecording();
                    isRecording = false;
                }
                else {
                    //start recording
                    startRecording();
                    if (checkPermissions()) {
                        isRecording = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        mediaRecorder = null;

        uploadAudio();
    }

    private void uploadAudio() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String recordPath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("/").getAbsolutePath();

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(recordPath));
        StorageReference filePath = audioReference.child("Audio").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }


    private void startRecording() {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss", Locale.TAIWAN);

        String recordPath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("/").getAbsolutePath();
        Date date = new Date();
        recordFile = "Heart Leaf" + formatter.format(date) + ".3gp";

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(recordPath + "/" + recordFile);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaRecorder.start();
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), recordPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{recordPermission}, PERMISSION_CODE);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working perfectly but when I upload the recorded audio file it didn't upload.
I found that the fault is in these lines :

```
filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

But I am unable to find what is the error and why I am unable to upload the audio file perfectly to Firebase Database.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
filePath.putFile(uri)
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // print your exception here
    }
})
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
})
```

**But as I can see you trying to upload a folder instead of a file. Here what you need to do.** Declare member

```
var recordingPath: Uri = null
```

Add this line at the end of the function startRecording() to save URL to your file

```
private void startRecording() {
    ...
    recordingPath = Uri.fromFile(new File(recordPath + "/" + recordFile));
}
```

So you can use it when uploading

```
private void uploadAudio() {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    Uri uri = recordingPath
    StorageReference filePath = audioReference.child("Audio").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your reply, but it is not still working and my storage rules are:     rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}             Can you tell me another way! to fix i      
              fix it.

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Comment: when you print the exception message from .addOnfailureListener, what you get?

Comment: when i stop recording it stops but progress dialog keeps continuously running that means the file don't successfully uploads to firebase storage.

Comment: when i print exception it shows that an unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response,   Also i have given the permission to the app and firebase storage is also connecting properly with the project

Comment: Will update my answer. You need to keep that `path` you recording to and use to upload.
Currently to generate filepath, as example: "some_address/Heart Leaf2021_06_04_10_00_00.3gp", but you trying to upload the folder instead "some_address".

Comment: hats off, you did it man, I was searching for that from 4 days. Thanks a lot.  but there is still a  problem, after uploading when i check the file it shows that the file is of type video. Can we be friends (Instagram)? Thanks again.